# Setting Article Preview Length in Joomla

Tags: joomla2.5

I admit that I'm quite new with Joomla. A customer has asked me a kind weird thing... he wants a preview on the article on the left and he wants that the see more link appear after a specific number of words.

For example, consider the full article:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
>   culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

He wants:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate" click here for more

How can I achieve this? Is there a module that does such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

It is common to display introductory text with a link to the rest of the article. To split an article into an introduction with a link to read more:

1. Open the Article for editing either by:

   - Click the Content > Article Manager menu item to go to the Article
     Manager, select the Article and click the Edit toolbar button.
   - Clicking the Add New Article button in the Control Panel.  If logged
   - in to the Front-end, you have appropriate permissions and are viewing
     the Article you wish to edit: Click the Edit toolbar button.
2. If you have not already done so, write the complete Article text in the editor.
3. Decide where you would like the introduction to finish and the read more link to appear. Place the cursor in this position.
4. Click the Read more... editor button at the bottom of the editor. A horizontal rule will appear where the split in the article is placed.

   - The horizontal rule will not be displayed in the Article. It is only
     used as a marker for the system when displaying the page.
   - The read more link may be removed by deleting in the same way as
     text. Select by clicking on the line, note the line break will NOT be
     highlighted when selected, however the horizontal bar icon on the
     WYSIWYG toolbar will show it is selected, then click delete.
5. Click the Save or Apply toolbar buttons to save the Article.

OBS

- The "read more" function works only in articles published in blog
  layout.
- The 'Show "readmore"' must be set to Show.
- The 'Show title with readmore' may be set to Show.
- The text for the readmore can be set globally with a language
  override and at the article itself.
- When the read more link is clicked the entire Article will be
  displayed unless the Article parameter Show Intro text has been set
  to Hide. In this case only the content after the read more link will
  be displayed.

source: http://docs.joomla.org/Splitting_an_Article_into_an_introduction_with_a_link_to_read_more